# How to build a scheduled reporting system

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, scheduler, system-design

I am interested to know the system design for a scheduled reporting system in which user can schedule any number of reports with any frequency

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I suggest starting here as a popular scheduling system - https://airflow.apache.org

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a lot more investigation into requirements before you can get a real answer
What I can do is talk about some of the things you'd need to consider e.g.

- "any number of reports with any frequency" is not something you'd be
  able to do you don't also have unlimited resources. what do you do when there aren't enough resources, which reports get to run
- Also you'd need to consider what happens if a report fails and then
  the next run comes - do you need to run the previous run or you can run the new one?
- when you run a schedule report and the previous run didn't finish yet - do you wait or start the next run?
- what technologies will the reports use
- is this an end-user facing system? do you need to show progress

etc. etc. - once you have better understanding of whats needed you could start to think about solutions :)